# When is a duplicate not a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, dupehammer

I recently earned my golden hammer for the [ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios) tag and have been carefully hitting things with it.

I just ran into [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50476399/passing-data-between-uiviewcontrollers), which is clearly a duplicate of several other nearly identical questions. This question was not tagged with [ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios), so I could only vote to close. My question here is not about that, however.

In the process, I ran across [Passing Data between View Controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers) and [Passing Data between View Controllers in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24222640/passing-data-between-view-controllers-in-swift). Seeing these questions, I took out my golden hammer, took careful aim and closed the latter as a duplicate of the former. The latter was more recent and did not have as complete answers as did the former.

Then I started to doubt my self. The latter question was limited to [swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift) while the former has answers for both [objective-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/objective-c) and [swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift).

Did I do the "right thing" here? Or should both questions have remained open despite one having superior answers that covered both languages? Did I just put a dent in my new hammer?

Comment: That is pretty doubtful.  The duplicate you hammered with never  mentions swift in the question nor the accepted answer.  That somebody decided to post a swift answer anyway there is, erm, you know.  It is going to be at least another decade or two before it catches up :)

Comment: IMO duplicate links should lead to the best answer - your duplicate link leads to a highly rated off-topic answer that hides beneath an accepted answer which is not relevant to the closed question. It just sounds wrong. But is it really? I... I just don't know.

Comment: In this case the "close if answer can solve the problem" rule is broken when there are wrong/off-topic answers........

Comment: Sounds like the consensus is to reopen it. Will do.